# Ionic 2 - Can't resolve all parameters for Storage error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an Ionic 2 application where I make use of Storage.
When I start the app, it crashes with the error message: Can't resolve all parameters for Storage: (?, ?).

I can't seem to find the error, who can help me?

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { EthylenePage } from '../pages/ethylene/ethylene';
import { PropylenePage } from '../pages/propylene/propylene';
import { TemporaryResultPage } from '../pages/temporary-result/temporary-result';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    EthylenePage,
    PropylenePage,
    TemporaryResultPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    PropylenePage,
    EthylenePage,
    TemporaryResultPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    Storage
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

In my package.json I have added this to my dependencies section:
 "@ionic/storage": "1.1.7"

Comment: Can you show your `package.json` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this http://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/

The documentation state

```
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
```

and

```
  imports: [      
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
```

You don't need to add Storage on providers part